# How to use R to extract data from Oanda?

Tags: r, quantmod

I am using `getSymbols` function to extract forex daily data from Oanda:

```
a <- getSymbols('EUR/USD', src='oanda', from=Sys.Date()-499, 
                to=Sys.Date(), auto.assign=FALSE)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in download.file(paste(oanda.URL, from.date, to.date, "exch=", currency.pair[1],  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://www.oanda.com/convert/fxhistory?lang=en&date1=12%2F09%2F13&date=04%2F22%2F15&date_fmt=us&exch=EUR&expr2=USD&margin_fixed=0&SUBMIT=Get+Table&format=CSV&redirected=1'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(oanda.URL, from.date, to.date, "exch=", currency.pair[1],  :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

It seems Oanda has changed the URL, I don't think I can overwrite the `getSymbols` function, so in this case, how to extract the data?

Comment: It works for me with `quantmod_0.4-4`. What is your version of `quantmod`?

Comment: Hi Pascal, thanks for replying, you mean you can run my code in R>?

Comment: Hmmm... yes, I can run it, as I said it works...

Comment: ok ,  i am updating my quantmod now

Comment: seems ok now. thank you so much Pascal....

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fImport` package with the code:

```
oandaSeries(symbols, from = NULL, to = Sys.timeDate(),
nDaysBack = 366, ...)
```

Detailed instructions are available [in the package manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fImport/fImport.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

This package works very well:

```
install.packages('ichimoku')
library(ichimoku)
data<-oanda('EUR/USD', granularity="H4")
```